# libavformat fails to link on Macos

Tags: c++, c, cmake, ffmpeg, libavformat

I'm trying to go through an ffmpeg tutorial however when I try to build my project I get the following error. I initialy thought that cmake's `find_path` and `find_library` was linking the wrong files `Mark Setchell` showed that this was not the case. Now I'm not sure why the linker errors are occurring. Here is the minimum example that fails to compile and the aforementioned error.

```
[build] [1/1 100% :: 0.076] Linking CXX executable example
[build] FAILED: example 
[build] : && /usr/bin/clang++ -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.o -o example  /usr/local/lib/libavformat.dylib && :
[build] Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
[build]   "avformat_open_input(AVFormatContext**, char const*, AVInputFormat const*, AVDictionary**)", referenced from:
[build]       _main in main.cpp.o
[build]   "avformat_free_context(AVFormatContext*)", referenced from:
[build]       _main in main.cpp.o
[build]   "avformat_alloc_context()", referenced from:
[build]       _main in main.cpp.o
[build] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
[build] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


find_path(AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIRS libavformat/avformat.h REQUIRED)
find_library(AVFORMAT_LIBRARY avformat REQUIRED)

message(WARNING "AVFORMAT_LIBRARY=" ${AVFORMAT_LIBRARY})
message(WARNING "AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIRS=" ${AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(example main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example ${AVFORMAT_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(example PRIVATE ${AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("example <input_file>");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    AVFormatContext *pFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();

    avformat_open_input(&pFormatContext, argv[1], nullptr, nullptr);
    printf("Format %s, duration %lld us", pFormatContext->iformat->long_name, pFormatContext->duration);


    avformat_free_context(pFormatContext);
}
```

Comment: The paths specified after PATHS in find_path and find_library command are searched last after many other paths. So, when the path/library is found earlier, the paths specified after PATHS are not searched at all. You can add the NO_DEFAULT_PATH keyword in the find_path and find_library command. Then only the paths after PATHS should be searched.

Comment: That makes sense. I added NO_DEFAULT_PATH to both but now I'm getting a new error. `Could not find AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIRS using the following files:libavformat/avformat.h`. I checked out the path and I found the header file `/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.0.1/include/libavformat/avformat.h` so the file does exist. I'm not sure why CMake is still complaining

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to use long paths with library names and versions like that with **homebrew**. It normally makes symlinks in `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` for you to use, then nothing needs changing when you do `brew upgrade`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell You're right. I checked the file in /usr/local/lib and it symlinks to /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.0.1. The question is wrong. The way I was using find_library and find_path is correct. The problems is that I'm still getting linker errors. I'll change the question to reflect this